# When I add ./ after URL session doesn't exist

Tags: php, apache

I'm using Apache 2.4 with PHP 7.

I don't know if this is a bug but when ever I add `./` after URL for example `mywebsite.com./index`, I get redirected to the index page even if I'm not logged in.

I'm not using any router, my pages get automatically included from a folder by the requested URL so for example I have a folder `/pages/` and inside is `index.php`, `register.php`, `me.php` and when someone visits `mywebsite.com/register` the register gets included, I have no idea if this is the problem, I hope someone can help me out.

Comment: Why are you adding the dot? and why not use `mywebsite.com/index.php`

Comment: Do you even check the authorization in the index?

Comment: I did it unpurpose but after i saw the page still being loaded i thought its a glitch or something.

Comment: i just reread the question, i dont think this is a glitch or anything, mywebsite.com. is a different domain than mywebsite.com and therefore probably has its own sessions, you could just debug that to be sure